# После установки Kubuntu bios перестал видеть загрузочные флешки

Tags: windows, usb, bios, kde, kubuntu

Вообщем, установил себе ОС Kubuntu, хочу вернуться на windows 10. 
Делал много загрузочных флешек, использовал DriveDroid. Во всех случаях bios не видит флешки.
Один раз изменил с legacy на uefi, вроде после этого bios перестал видеть флешки.
Также, настройки BIOS не меняются вообще.

Comment: А какую версию Kubuntu поставили? Не 17ю ли?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не в ОС. Сейчас наверняка стоит загрузка через UEFI и все загрузочные устройства обрабатываются им.

Чтобы вернуть загрузку с флешки необходимо

- отключить в BIOS режим загрузки через UEFI (каким образом - это уже зависит от материнки, в разных моделях могут называться по разному, например включить Legacy режим)
- поставить USB устройство загрузки первым, при этом смотрите чтоб именно Legacy USB стояло первым, а не что-то вроде UEFI USB.